# InvalidQueryException when trying to create column family in Cassandra via unit

Tags: cassandra, cql3, datastax, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-2.1

I have a 3 node cassandra cluster and via my unit test in Java, I first create a keyspace and then create a column family within that keyspace. Sometimes the unit tests passes but randomly I keep getting the following error. I am using the latest datastax 2.1.4 java driver and the cassandra version in 2.1.0.

```
com.symc.edp.database.nosql.NoSQLPersistenceException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Cannot add column family 'testmaxcolumnstable' to non existing keyspace 'testmaxcolumnskeyspace'.
    at com.symc.edp.database.nosql.cassandra.CassandraCQLTableEditor.createTable(CassandraCQLTableEditor.java:67)
    at com.symc.edp.database.nosql.cassandra.TestCassandraWideRowPerformance.testWideRowInserts(TestCassandraWideRowPerformance.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Cannot add column family 'testmaxcolumnstable' to non existing keyspace 'testmaxcolumnskeyspace'.
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:35)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:289)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:205)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:52)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:36)
    at com.symc.edp.database.nosql.cassandra.CassandraCQLTableEditor.createTable(CassandraCQLTableEditor.java:65)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidConfigurationInQueryException: Cannot add column family 'testmaxcolumnstable' to non existing keyspace 'testmaxcolumnskeyspace'.
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:104)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:140)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:249)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.onSet(RequestHandler.java:421)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.messageReceived(Connection.java:697)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:70)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And in the system.log file of cassandra I see the following exception:

```
ERROR [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2015-01-28 15:08:24,286 ErrorMessage.java:218 - Unexpected exception during request
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:375) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:311) ~[netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:878) ~[netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:225) ~[netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:114) ~[netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:507) ~[netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:464) ~[netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:378) ~[netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:350) ~[netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116) ~[netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
INFO  [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2015-01-28 15:13:01,051 MigrationManager.java:229 - Create new Keyspace: KSMetaData{name=testmaxcolumnskeyspace, strategyClass=SimpleStrategy, strategyOptions={replication_factor=1}, cfMetaData={}, durableWrites=true, userTypes=org.apache.cassandra.config.UTMetaData@790ee1bb}
INFO  [MigrationStage:1] 2015-01-28 15:13:01,058 ColumnFamilyStore.java:856 - Enqueuing flush of schema_keyspaces: 512 (0%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:7] 2015-01-28 15:13:01,059 Memtable.java:326 - Writing Memtable-schema_keyspaces@1727029917(138 serialized bytes, 3 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:7] 2015-01-28 15:13:01,077 Memtable.java:360 - Completed flushing /usr/share/apache-cassandra-2.1.0/bin/../data/data/system/schema_keyspaces-b0f2235744583cdb9631c43e59ce3676/system-schema_keyspaces-ka-103-Data.db (175 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1422485457803, position=1181)
```

Also, I verified via devcenter, the keyspace didn't get created.

Comment: I responded to this on the mailing list before noticing the SO question. If you're going to cross-post, please provide a link in one or the other so the conversation can happen in one place.

Comment: Sure, will keep that in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, my guess is you need a sleep in between creating the keyspace and trying to create tables in it.  You probably need to give the keyspace definition a couple seconds to propagate to all the nodes in your cluster before you try to use it.

Comment: The problem is the keyspace itself didn't get created. It is throwing Connection reset by peer exception when trying to create keyspace.

Comment: That could be because the client is crashing when trying to create a table in a keyspace that hasn't propagated yet, so Cassandra sees the connection reset when the client dies.  Do you have a sleep between the creation of the keyspace and the creation of tables?

Answer (score 0):

It would help as noted to see your configuration class. We are using `ClassPathCQLDataSet` to issue our statements and create `keyspace` at same go ([link to ClassPathCqlDataSet documentation](https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit/blob/master/cassandra-unit/src/main/java/org/cassandraunit/dataset/cql/ClassPathCQLDataSet.java), note that boolean on position 2 and 3 tell it to create and delete keyspace). `db.cql` is file where we hold create table statments. Here is our configuration which might help you:

```
package some.package;

import org.cassandraunit.CQLDataLoader;
import org.cassandraunit.dataset.cql.ClassPathCQLDataSet;
import org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

@Configuration
@Profile({"test"})
public class TestCassandraConfig implements DisposableBean {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestCassandraConfig.class);

    private final String CQL = "db.cql";

    @Value("${cassandra.contact_points:localhost}")
    private String contact_points;
    @Value("${cassandra.port:9142}")
    private int port;
    @Value("${cassandra.keyspace:test}")
    private String keyspace;

    private static Cluster cluster;
    private static Session session;
    private static SessionProxy sessionProxy;

    @Bean
    public Session session() throws Exception {
        if (session == null) {
            initialize();
        }

        return sessionProxy;
    }

    @Bean
    public TestApplicationContext testApplicationContext() {
        return new TestApplicationContext();
    }

    private void initialize() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Starting embedded cassandra server");
        EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra("another-cassandra.yaml");

        LOGGER.info("Connect to embedded db");
        cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(contact_points).withPort(port).build();
        session = cluster.connect();

        LOGGER.info("Initialize keyspace");
        final CQLDataLoader cqlDataLoader = new CQLDataLoader(session);
        cqlDataLoader.load(new ClassPathCQLDataSet(CQL, false, true, keyspace));
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        if (cluster != null) {
            cluster.close();
            cluster = null;
        }
    }
}
```