# Connection reset by peer exception when creating keyspace in Cassandra 2.1.0 cluster

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-2.1

I have a 3 node cassandra 2.1.0 cluster and I am trying to create a keyspace via Java unit test using datastax 2.1.4 java driver. But I see the following error in Cassandra system.log file randomly when I try to create a keyspace:

```
ERROR [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2015-01-28 15:08:24,286 ErrorMessage.java:218 - Unexpected exception during request
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:375) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:311) ~[netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:878) ~[netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:225) ~[netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:114) ~[netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:507) ~[netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:464) ~[netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:378) ~[netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:350) ~[netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116) ~[netty-all-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
```

Anyone has any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [InvalidQueryException when trying to create column family in Cassandra via unit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28204414/invalidqueryexception-when-trying-to-create-column-family-in-cassandra-via-unit)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you set all the nodes as contact points the problem seems to go away.

Give nodes A, B, C:

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster
import com.datastax.driver.core.ProtocolOptions.Compression

val builder: Cluster.Builder = Cluster.builder
builder.addContactPoint(A.address)
builder.addContactPoint(B.address)
builder.addContactPoint(C.address)

val cluster: Cluster = builder.withCompression(Compression.SNAPPY).build
```